# C programming histogram

Tags: c, histogram

I'm getting an error on line number 8 that it needs an expected identifier '(' before a numeric constant, but I can't seem to fix it.  Please help.  This code is supposed to take each grade and create a histogram.

```
/* Histogram of Frequency of Different Characters in Input */

#include<stdio.h>
#define ch_grade 32  

int main(void)
{
char ch_grade [32] = {A, B, C, D, f, I, b, C, d, F, I, a, C, D, F, I, A, B, D, F, I, A, B, c, I, D, F, F, A, B, a, b};

int c,i,j;

int character[ch_grade];

for(i=0;i<ch_grade;++i)
    character[i] = 0;

while((c=getchar())!=EOF)
    ++character[c];

for(i=0;i<ch_grade;++i)
{
    putchar(i);

    for(j=0;j<character[i];++j)
        putchar('*');

    putchar('\n');
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is `ch_grade` supposed to be?

Comment: `#define ch_grade 32` : Use a different name. E.g `#define CH_Grade 32`

Comment: `putchar(i);` You must be converted to a symbol.

Comment: Note that because you `#define ch_grade 32`, the compiler interprets `char ch_grade [32]` as `char 32 [32]`. You need to make sure that you use different names for different items.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put you char literals each inside ' ', e.g.`'A', 'B'` etc.